# Trisecting angle equivalence of constructing a segment

Tags: geometry, galois-theory, cubics, angle

After reading Wikipedia and some previous questions asked in this site, I still don't understand this.

Following the Pierre Wantzel. 
Triple angle formula cos(3theta ) and getting a polynomial p(x). 
The conclusion was that p(x) is irreducible over integers for 
Angle 60 degrees( clearly trisecting that would give 20 degrees of it was solvable ).

I want to see the actual figure with explanation of how trisecting angle is equivalent to constructing a SEGMENTS  such that their length ratio is cos(theta ) .

Also, is proving for only  60 degrees enough to conclude that it can't be trisected or equivalently solve p(x) ?

Note: Haven't done Galois theory and Fields. 
Thank you for any info.

Here is the link: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection

Answer (score 1):

Regarding equivalence of trisecting an angle and constructing segments
in the ratio $\cos(\theta)$:

To trisect the angle $3\theta$ means that you must construct an angle
equal to $\frac13(3\theta)$, that is, $\theta$.

If you can trisect $3\theta$, that is,
construct angle $\theta$, you can construct a right triangle
with angle $\theta$ at one vertex. The length of the leg adjacent 
to the angle $\theta$ is $\cos(\theta)$ times the length of the hypotenuse.
So you will then have two segments (the leg and hypotenuse)
whose lengths have ratio $\cos(\theta)$.

Conversely, if you can somehow construct two segments whose lengths are
in the ratio $\cos(\theta)$, you can construct a right triangle
using the shorter of these segments as one leg of the triangle
and the longer segment as the hypotenuse.
The angle between these two sides will then be $\theta$,
and you will have trisected $3\theta$.

Regarding whether it's enough to show that $60$ degrees cannot be trisected:
yes.

We know of course that there are certain angles we can trisect.
If you happen to know that an angle is equal to $180^\circ$,
or $90^\circ$, or $45^\circ$, for example,
you can easily trisect it.
But when people speak of the problem of 
"trisecting the angle with straightedge and compass,"
they are asking whether there is a procedure
using only compass and straightedge that is guaranteed *always* to
construct one-third of a given angle, no matter what angle you are given.
"No matter what angle you are given" does not mean 
"no matter what angle you are given, unless it's $60$ degrees."